# Open an accordion while using <a href="#link.html">link</a> & <a name="link"></a>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I usually get my codes from: https://www.w3schools.com. There is also an accordion to take with this code;

However when I use link -> to  The accordion doesn't jump open but stays closed. Does someone know how to open the accordion if someone links a link which has content inside an accordion.

Thank you.

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].onclick = function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight){
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

 /* Style the buttons that are used to open and close the accordion panel */
button.accordion {
    background-color: #530010;
    color: #FFF;
 font-weight: bolder;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    transition: 0.4s;
 border-radius: 5px;
}

/* Add a background color to the button if it is clicked on (add the .active class with JS), and when you move the mouse over it (hover) */
button.accordion.active, button.accordion:hover {
    background-color: #a20121;
}

/* Style the accordion panel. Note: hidden by default */
div.panel {
    padding: 0px 5px;    
 margin-bottom: 5px;
 background-color: #none;
    max-height: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}

button.accordion:after {
    content: '\02795'; /* Unicode character for "plus" sign (+) */
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #FFF;
 font-weight: bolder;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

button.accordion.active:after {
    content: "\2796"; /* Unicode character for "minus" sign (-) */
}
```

```html
<a href="schedule.html#0906">2018.09.06</a>(木) 今池GROW<br><br>

<button class="accordion"><a name="0906">■</a>2018/09/06(木)今池GROW </button>
<div class="panel">
<p>
Testing
</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi! Please correct your snippet so it A) Doesn't show an error message when you click **Run code snippet**, and B) *Does* show us the problem.

Comment: So you would need to add additional code to detect it....

Comment: Your question is not clear enough

Comment: Please don't use W3Schools as a reference. Their articles are often outdated and sometimes just plain wrong. MDN is far more comprehensive and accurate.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to MDN!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a little bit of trouble understanding what you were asking initially, but I took a stab at it anyways!

Added ID's to the .accordion buttons.  Added .accordion-link class for your text links.  When accordion-links are clicked, the hash is isolated, and used to trigger a click event on the accordion button with a corresponding ID.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ya6vtosc/25/

JS

```
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].onclick = function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight){
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  }
}

// get list of links by class
var links = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion-link");

var linksLength = links.length;
for(var i=0; i < linksLength; i++){
  links[i].onclick = function(e){
    // preventDefault is probably optional
    // depending on your application
    e.preventDefault();

    // isolate the hash
    var hash = e.path[0].hash;

    // remove # from hash
    hash = hash.substring(1, hash.length);

    // select by id using hash
    document.getElementById(hash).click();
  }
```

HTML

```
<a href="schedule.html#0906" class="accordion-link">2018.09.06</a>(木) 今池GROW<br><br>


<button class="accordion" id="0906">2018/09/06(木)今池GROW </button>
<div class="panel">
<p>
Testing
</p>
</div>
```

EDIT - I also removed your link tag from your button...not sure if a tags are allowed in buttons or not off the top of my head, but it didn't feel right so I kiboshed them.

Comment: Thank you so much, that's exactly what I mean!! Sorry that I was unclear!

Comment: One more question: how to jump from index to schedule?  Just as here: [link(]http://reirei.nagoya/index.html)  but that it also opens up the accordion.

Comment: I think you mean so it works as a regular html anchor link as well.   Try removing the e.preventDefault() line from the JavaScript

Comment: Another question; the code doesn't seem to work in firefox and internetexplorer. Then if you click on the button, it won't open the accordion. Chrome is fine.

Comment: I also removed the e.preventDefault() line  but things stayed the same as it was.  So if I click on the button on index -> it jumps to schedule but it doesn't open the accordion.

Comment: replace e.preventDefault() with e.stopPropagation();  I tested in a fiddle and it works this way.

Comment: Yes it works; however, if I click on the button(The RED date button; 2018.08.31) at schedule.html when using IE or Firefox the accordion doesn't open. [link]http://reirei.nagoya/schedule.html.  Also when I jump from index to schedule the accordion also doesn't open automatically.

Comment: replace "var hash = e.path.hash"  with... "var hash = e.target.hash"...tested working in FF and Chrome.  Fiddle updated: https://jsfiddle.net/ya6vtosc/34/