# Button opens and jumps accordion while clicking on it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I actually asked this before, however I didn't got what I actually wanted.

[To my old topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52006937/open-an-accordion-while-using-a-href-link-htmllink-a-a-name-link-a)

It's for this website: http://n-p-cain.com/schedule.html

I wish, if you click on the "date" button in the "event menu section" that you will jump to that date in the "event list" and also will open the accordion, now the accordion stays closed (if I name  class="accordion-link1" or if you click on the button in the "event menu" the accordion will open but you will not jump to it (if I use the code below).

```js
     var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
      acc[i].onclick = function() {
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (panel.style.maxHeight){
          panel.style.maxHeight = null;
        } else {
          panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
        }
      }
    }

    // get list of links by class
    var links = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion-link");

    var linksLength = links.length;
    for(var i=0; i < linksLength; i++){
      links[i].onclick = function(e){
        // preventDefault is probably optional
        // depending on your application
        e.preventDefault();

        // isolate the hash
        var hash = e.target.hash;

        // remove # from hash
        hash = hash.substring(1, hash.length);

        // select by id using hash
        document.getElementById(hash).click();
      }
    }
```

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

 /* Style the buttons that are used to open and close the accordion panel */
button.accordion {
    background-color: #020725;
    color: #FFF;
 font-weight: bolder;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 10px;
 margin: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
    width: 98%;
    text-align: left;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    transition: 0.4s;
 border-radius: 5px;
}

/* Add a background color to the button if it is clicked on (add the .active class with JS), and when you move the mouse over it (hover) */
button.accordion.active, button.accordion:hover {
    background-color: #132437;
}

/* Style the accordion panel. Note: hidden by default */
div.panel {
    padding: 1px;    
 margin-bottom: 5px;
 background-color: #none;
    max-height: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}

button.accordion:after {
    content: '\02795'; /* Unicode character for "plus" sign (+) */
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #FFF;
 font-weight: bolder;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

button.accordion.active:after {
    content: "\2796"; /* Unicode character for "minus" sign (-) */
}
```

```html
    <div class="link_"><a href="schedule.html#0510i" class="accordion-link">2020.05.10</a></div><div class="link1">(日) littleHEARTS.大阪店</div> 
     
     
         
  
  <button class="accordion" id="0510i">5月10日 littleHEARTS.大阪店※時間未定</button> 
<div class="panel"><div class="p">
※詳細発表になるまでは、店舗への問い合わせはご遠慮ください。
 </div></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that, when you click one of the date links, it's grabbing the hash *before* it's been changed.

Answer (score 0):

I think that it would work if you changed `var hash = e.target.hash` to `var hash = window.location.hash`. The click event object does not return a target.hash that I am aware of.

```
    // get list of links by class
    var links = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion-link");

    var linksLength = links.length;
    for(var i=0; i < linksLength; i++){
      links[i].onclick = function(e){

        // isolate the hash
        var hash = window.location.hash;

        // remove # from hash
        hash = hash.substring(1, hash.length);

        // select by id using hash
        document.getElementById(hash).click();
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, that opens the window, however you don't jump to it.

Comment: Try removing the e.preventDefault() too.

Comment: sweet that worked! thank you!!!  However it's still buggy.  If you have opened one and you close it (or leave it open). And you want to jump to a different one. it somehow close or open the previous one.  you can try it to see what I mean  http://n-p-cain.com/schedule.html